# Javascript classList.remove not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check this fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq26wfer/)

HTML:

```
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class=" someStyle">1</span>/<span class="otherStyle">15</span>
    </td>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class=" someStyle">2</span>/<span class="otherStyle">16</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class="">3</span>/<span class="">17</span>
    </td>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class="otherStyle">4</span>/<span class=" someStyle">18</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class="otherStyle">5</span>/<span class=" someStyle">19</span>
    </td>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class="">6</span>/<span class="">20</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class="">7</span>/<span class="">21</span>
    </td>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class=" someStyle">8</span>/<span class="otherStyle">22</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class="">9</span>/<span class="">23</span>
    </td>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class="otherStyle">10</span>/<span class=" someStyle">24</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class="otherStyle">11</span>/<span class=" someStyle">25</span>
    </td>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class="otherStyle">12</span>/<span class=" someStyle">26</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class=" someStyle">13</span>/<span class="otherStyle">27</span>
    </td>
    <th>Some text</th>
    <td class="align">
      <span class=" someStyle">14</span>/<span class="otherStyle">28</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myTbl = document.getElementsByClassName("myTable")[0];

var tSomeStyleClasses = myTbl.getElementsByClassName("someStyle");
console.log(tSomeStyleClasses);
for (i=0;i<tSomeStyleClasses.length;i++) {
    console.log(tSomeStyleClasses[i].classList);
    //tSomeStyleClasses[i].classList.remove("someStyle");
}

var tOtherStyleClasses = myTbl.getElementsByClassName("otherStyle");
console.log(tOtherStyleClasses);
for (i=0;i<tOtherStyleClasses.length;i++) {
    console.log(tOtherStyleClasses[i].classList);
    //tOtherStyleClasses[i].classList.remove("otherStyle");
}
```

And check the console log. There are 10 entries for each, someStyle and otherStyle. Now uncomment `//tSomeStyleClasses[i].classList.remove("someStyle");` and `//tOtherStyleClasses[i].classList.remove("otherStyle");` and run the fiddle. Check the console log again. 2 x 10 styles should be removed, but instead it removes only 5 styles.
I wonder why?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The value returned from `.getElementsByClassName()` is a **live** NodeList.  That it's "live" means that as you change the elements in the list, the list itself automatically updates. Thus, when you *remove* the class that you used to find the elements, the list gets shorter. Because you're iterating with a numeric index, you end up skipping elements.

A good way to deal with that is to use a simple `while` loop and operate only on the first element of the list until the list is empty:

```
var tSomeStyleClasses = myTbl.getElementsByClassName("someStyle");

while (tSomeStyleClasses.length) {
    tSomeStyleClasses[0].classList.remove("someStyle");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Because `getElementsByClassName` gives you a **live** list of matching elements. When you remove the class from the element at index `0`, the list is updated immediately to remove that element from the list and shuffle all the others down. Since you then increment `i`, the element *now* at index 0 doesn't get processed.

Either:

1. Work your way through the list backward, or
2. Use `document.querySelectorAll(".someStyle")`, which returns a snapshot list, not a live one

Comment: 3. Or the `while` loop Pointy suggested. :-D

Comment: I've always wondered what mad genius came up with the "live" node list idea in the first place, because it's really unusual.

Comment: @Pointy :-) Yeah. When browsers were a lot slower, it made it more efficient if code needed to keep track of things across operations. Also, some browsers maintain these lists *anyway*, so it was efficient just to return the existing list rather than take a snapshot. (`getElementsByTagName("a") === getElementsByTagName("a")` is true) But as you say, fairly unusual and confuses people easily.

Comment: Which one is quicker? querySelectorAll, while loop or if loop with decrementing index?

Comment: @Tomo: You'd have to test your target browsers, if it's important. It's rarely important.

Comment: I chose the while loop, but I feel there's a better choice. I just wondered which one is (let's say) more correct or quicker.

Comment: @Tomo: None of them is "more correct." For speed, again, you'd have to test your target browsers; I bet it varies.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method that I've discovered and it works perfectly is using:
[-someElementToRemoveClassName-.classList.value = ""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8t1M.png)

It clears off the entire ClassName List and returns it to original state, letting ya guys to re-add the transition class again and makes the transition reappear again as usual.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It would probably make your answer clearer if you simply wrote `classList.value = " ";` inside a code-block and removed the image link that isn't really needed

Answer (score 0):

For those who prefer `for` loops over `while` loops and function names like `getElementsByTagName` over `querySelectorAll`, you can also use the same function and create the snapshot yourself using `Array.from`:

```
Array.from(getElementsByClassName("someStyle"))
```

or spread syntax:

```
[...getElementsByClassName("someStyle")]
```

You would then be able to iterate over this with a `for` loop of your choice (though remember only some of them work nicely with `async`/`await`).

*Note: I couldn't just add this as a comment for lack of rep, but this feels like it could have just been a comment on T.J. Crowder's answer.*